# Deeply nested form and object attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

class Equipment `has_many :equipment_maintenances` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for : equipment_maintenances, allow_destroy: true`

class EquipmentMaintenance `has_many :equipment_maintenanceitems` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for : equipment_maintenanceitems, allow_destroy: true`

The following form can properly generate the HTML to update the grandchildren (i.e. `name="equipment[equipment_maintenance_attributes][0][equipment_maintenanceitems_attributes][1][active]"` as follows:

```
<%= form_for @equipments do |equipment| %>
  <% @equipment_maintenances.each do |equipment_maintenance| %>
    <%= equipment.fields_for :equipment_maintenance do |em| %>
      <%= em.fields_for :equipment_maintenanceitems do |f| %>
         <%= f.check_box :active %>
         <%= f.text_field :order %>
         <%# equipment_maintenanceitem.name  %>
         <%= f.select :frequenc, [3,4,6,12] %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= equipment.submit %>
<% end %>
```

However, I have not found the proper syntax to reference the name of the grandchild `equipment_maintenanceitem.name`

**Update**  While the original question was properly answered, the question was incompletely stated.  EquipmentMaintenanceItem `belongs_to :ordinary_maintenanceitem` and the goal is to get `equipment_maintenanceitem.ordinary_maintenanceitem.name`

Comment: you just want to show the name of the maintenanceitem?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the original formulation of the question, the answer is:

```
<%= f.object.name %>
```

Under the updated context, the answer is:

```
<%= OrdinaryMaintenanceItem('id = ?',f.object.maintenanceitem_id).pluck("name") %>
```

*not very efficient and needs to be cleaned up for array and string symbology...*

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for @equipments do |equipment| %>
  <% @equipment_maintenances.each do |equipment_maintenance| %>
    <%= equipment.fields_for :equipment_maintenance do |em| %>
      <%= em.fields_for :equipment_maintenanceitems do |f| %>
         <%= f.check_box :active %>
         <%= f.text_field :order %>
         <%= f.label :name  %>
         <%= f.select :frequenc, [3,4,6,12] %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= equipment.submit %>
<% end %>
```

A simple way is to use label to show the name of the equipment_maintenanceitems

Comment: Ah!  Sounds silly.  But I did not realize I was assuming something. The question was thus misformulated (now updated).  I am attempting to get the related object's attribute.

Comment: Also, the solution suggested will return "Name", not the content of that attribute